# make php time, add one day in todays time

Tags: php, sql

I am creating a application where I am storing the details of users. One of the field is the time created and number of days the user want his account to be active.
I am using `date('c')` to store the time in `created` table field. Now if the user selects that he wants his account to be active for only one day, how can I add that one day to the current `date('c')` and store it into my next table field `valid_till`.

Later I was planning to check if the current `date('c')` is between the `created` and `valid_tll` field, then the users account is active, else the account is deleted.

I want to use sql triggers to delete the account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$valid_till = date('c', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

You can read more about the possible formats on in the [Supported Date and Time Formats](http://www.php.net/datetime.formats.php) section of PHP manual.

Comment: what about deleting that row using triggers, any idea on that

Comment: SQL triggers only work when a modification is applied to a table. They do not work on a time interval. I would suggest you run a garbage collection script periodically that simply deletes accounts if `date('c') >= $valid_till`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use SQL, depending on the engine you are using, you can use something like create= NOW(), expires NOW() + interval number_of_days, sql engines handles the dates for you and you wont need to go to the troubles of creating php times and work with them..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a SQL based solution. You can translate this into an update or insert.

```
SELECT
    `created`,
    CONCAT(
        DATE_FORMAT(
            DATE_ADD(SUBSTRING(`created`,1,10), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d'
        ),
        RIGHT(`created`,15)
    ) AS 'valid_till'
FROM `some_table`
```

But I would recommend using the SQL `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` instead of the PHP date function and a row with the `TIMESTAMP` datatype instead of a `(VAR)CHAR` for you to make easier calculations in the SQL side.